# Insert arbitrary (non-Unicode) glyph in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, symbols, fontspec

I am creating a LaTeX template to my University's standards. The official OpenType font "UnB Pro" (freely available at http://marca.unb.br/fontesunb.php) has a special glyph to insert the logo. This glyph has no Unicode number (not even in private use area) according to FontForge, but it does have a name, `<ass_completa_CONT>`. How can I use it in LaTeX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\XeTeXglyphindex "ass_completa_CONT" \relax
```

should expand to the integer glyphid then
`\XeTeXglyph ⟨glyph slot⟩`
should typeset it,

so

```
\XeTeXglyph \XeTeXglyphindex "ass_completa_CONT" \relax
```

Probably works...

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!